# Difference between '<>' and 'Is NOT' in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql

I don't get it.

I had this expression and it didn't work.

```
IF @LocationName <> NULL AND
@Latitude <> NULL AND
@Longitude <> NULL AND
@Zoom <> NULL AND
@MapTypeId <> NULL
BEGIN
... 
END
```

I changed it to this expression.

```
IF @LocationName Is NOT NULL  AND
@Latitude Is NOT NULL AND
@Longitude Is NOT NULL AND
@Zoom Is NOT NULL AND
@MapTypeId Is NOT NULL
BEGIN
... 
END
```

And it worked...

WTH?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As expected.

Every comparison against NULL is always UNKNOWN (which equates to false).

Also known as [Three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29) (Wikipedia) and [MSDN/SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use comparison operators when dealing with `NULL` values.  `NULL` isn't really any value so you can't compare it - when you try to compare it will return `UNKOWN`.

You have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

[IS [NOT] NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx)

[Null Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can't check if something is equal (or not) to `NULL`, as `NULL` is of unknown value and type.

You have to check if it `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of `<>` can be modified by setting [`SET ANSI_NULLS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

EDIT: However, it is not advisable to do so, as the text in the page above suggests.

Answer (score 1):

That's [ternary logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504.aspx). It is one of main SQL features and you should always remember it.

Comment: Not really, Ternary means there are 3 comparable items, but `NULL != NULL`

Comment: @ck: That makes it ternary.  There are three states: true, false and completely fouled up.  (I'm not a fan of NULL values in SQL....)

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: Well, then I believe there can only be three opinions on this matter...